# Separating values in a cell into multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have these values in one excel row that was imported from a csv file

```
    Col1             Col2    Col3   Col4
name@email.com     `value1  value2  value 3`
Name2@email.com
name3@email.com
```

I need these separated into 3 rows with the same value of cols 2-4 in each row.    Note: the number of entries in column 1 is not consistent. I could range from 1 to 12 lines.  And, there may be duplicates.
I found some code that was supposed to remove duplicate which would have helped but it would not be the complete solution and besides, it didn't work.  I also found some formulas but none of them were exactly what I wanted either.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `SPLIT` function to split the cell with more than one lines into an array. You can split at every line break using the Line feed character (character code 10).

For example, if you start with the following data:

[image] 
 [Reproduce this data](https://itty.bitty.site/#/data:text/html;charset=utf-8;bxze64,XQAAAAI+AwAAAAAAAAAeHApGZZfl7uxUBAgLO0E7DzhWjmMKbMmLnCOC4KmFVWztjLN85fKcLrsyDtS+RE2YQtqxsr69I6x320+qe9jCnK/0eX/A65fgdjrMExV/TS/EW0pdneRo72P808cVxx1OFfw4GhWAuf8eZmkOUI2+VIeefdpTekhACTwJ46JYuDyneIfrQQUDq8xwwU+maLpnsAqp9DrHh2Oqs38i/+gKSj/RPp3ChcLzRZj1xU4676cWYArOySGnYjtDiN134Q+1IrwMLDaewBSBE8RXbrNsWN962alF1yBmDjX+bQ7fYtYBf8hUYM0dBGc6jHFWl65s3yHAi6NqvkTeIyu3ID0ZhkWfJPcNEbT4r+P2v3mZc3TmvtAB1NVNqByASly8MabBjGco9EMDOXtPeX4ADBAzPEEg184Nk28DuRfTf+/QClaDSQl2xUz/45QXrQ==)

And run the following:

```
Sub SplitRow()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("MySheet")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")

    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = Split(rng, Chr(10))
        
    'Insert the number of rows needed
    If UBound(MyArray) > 0 Then
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(MyArray), 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End If
    
    'Write the array to sheet
    rng.Resize(UBound(MyArray) + 1, 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
    
    'Copy over the other columns
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To UBound(MyArray) + 1
            rng.Offset(i, j).Value2 = rng.Offset(0, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

You'd then have this:

[image]

---

#### Potential problem with line breaks

Note that there might not be any line feed character in your cell. In that case, you'd have to find another character to serve as `delimiter` to split.

To know if you cell contains a line feed, you can select the cell and run the following :

```
Sub StringDrillDown(str As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(AFTER:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    ws.Range("A1") = "Character"
    ws.Range("B1") = "Ascii Code"
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value2 = Mid$(str, i, 1)
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value2 = Asc(Mid$(str, i, 1))
    Next i

End Sub
```

For exemple, if I run it on the original content of Range A1 (before spliting), I would get :

[image]

Hopefully, your CSV is formatted in a way where you have a character between each element so you can split them properly. If not, you might have to have a look into regular expression.

---

#### Cautionary notes:

- The SPLIT function is zero-based meaning that the first element of MyArray is MyArray(0).
- If you plan to run this procedure on multiple rows of data, make sure that your loop starts from the bottom to avoid issues with inserted rows messing up the rows position.

Comment: Thanks DecimalTurn but I get an error on this line:
rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(MyArray), 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
it is an object defined error

Comment: @aoswald It's probably because `rng` doesn't contain any Linefeed character and you get ubound(MyArray) = 0. I've edited my answer to account for this possibility.

Comment: Thanks @DecimalTurn but now I don't get an error message. I get nothing at all

Comment: @aoswald Note that there might not be any linefeed character in your cell. In that case, you'd have to find another character to serve as delimiter to split. Maybe use Chr(32) for the space character for instance.

Comment: @aoswald - I've added code to reproduce the data I'm using, so you can at least replicate my results. I've also added a section about the potential problem with line breaks. Hope this helps.